# Cannot edit or overwrite in explorer hosts file, even as admin

Tags: windows-7, hosts

I have followed all the options I can find here. Opened hosts as administrator but cannot save 'in use by another process'. Saved in \temp as 'hosts'. Run explorer as administrator copying over ...drivers\ec\hosts - gives need permission error. (Windows 7 Home 64)

Answer (score 1):

The hosts file may be protected by Antivirus or other security software, check for that and temporarily disable it prior to making your changes.

Alternately, this has worked for me in similar circumstances: Open the Windows Explorer with 'Run as Administrator' (ctrl right-click ...) then in the ..\etc\ folder create a file 'new_hosts' as you wish it to be, rename 'hosts' to 'old_hosts' then rename new_hosts to hosts, restart the network service or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The hosts file have other permission/rights for read/write/execute.

And even the Administrator miss those rights.

It seems you need to change the rights of the hosts file.

E.g.

> open properties of hosts.txt
>
> open the tab security
>
> choose the user you need and click elaborate (below)
>
> allow all fields, (and don't forget to set it back, after you changed your file)
>
> Click okay